# special character validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to write a validator which could validate the bunch of commas like (,,,,,,,,,)
if single comma(,) is there then its ok . 
here is my code

```
function test() {

    var iChars = ",,";
    for (var i = 0; i < document.mform.show_time1.value.length; i++) {
        if (iChars.indexOf(document.mform.show_time1.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
            alert("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but the above script is also validating (,)  that i don't want .

Any idea how to do that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you trying to find out string which has multipe ,,,, in it

For Example

```
string = " I have ,,,, this many commas ?"
```

then your test() function should be something like this.

```
function test(){

    if(string.indexOf(",,") > -1 ){
        alert("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
    }

}
```

I hope this helps, or please clarify the question once again.

Answer (score 2):

There are regular expressions to help you. Please read the [Mozilla MDN pages on `RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions); this will help.

Comment: I would go with the superior MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions I really wish google would delete w3schools from their index :S

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: While w3schools may well be awful, your edit takes a mostly-useless answer and makes it almost *completely* useless by removing any kind of reference from it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It is more harmful to link to <that site> than to link to nothing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I have *absolutely* no love for that site, but I strongly disagree. Replacing it with something useful is one thing, just stripping it out is completely wrong.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I refer you back to my previous comment. If the original link had been to http://www.4chan.com then I would also have removed it, with precisely the same effect on the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Nonsense. It's not okay to impose your agenda in that way, and hyperbole does nothing to support your argument.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It's not "my agenda". It's objectivity regarding the usefulness of answers, and conversely the danger of some other answers. I don't think we'll find any "knowledgeable" programmer who can contest that -- more than this just being some personal preference against w3schools -- the continued propagation of links to said site is _actively harmful_. Also, I employed no hyperbole whatsoever; any such inference is completely down to your own biases.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No. Your opinion is not fact. w3schools may not be great (I'd even say it definitely isn't great, or even good), but it has more relevant content about regular expressions than 4chan.com. Hence, irrelevant hyperbole (and noise). Removing a relevant if imperfect reference for **no reference at all** is actively harmful, arguably vandalism. You can say what you want, but there's no getting away from that basic point. Now. You've said your piece. I've said mine. I'm moving on, I have things to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: There really is no need to be rude.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't believe I was. I believe I was at least as polite as you were. If you believe otherwise, you have my apology for any perceived offense. It was not my intention.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As I assume this exchange is now ended, we should both remove all of our comments here, as they do nothing to enhance the answer. We can save the moderators the time (since they do now go clean up comments whose usefulness has gone).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: If a mod decides that they are not useful then that's fine. I disagree.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Okay, that's fine. Best,